# Reading the pad dimensions from the data sheet

Tags: pcb, footprint, pad

[image]

I would like to know in what **units** are these dimensions?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. This question does not state the origin of this diagram so no-one can definitively answer it. Please edit you question (not in comments) and add a link to the source document, along with adding the part manufacturer and name.  Again, welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions are given both in inches and in millimeters. Inches on top and millimeters are at bottom in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions are given in both metric (mm) and imperial (inches) however one is a converted and rounded version of the other.

If you want the best accuracy it would be best to divine which is the 'original' and design using those numbers.

In particular, the pitch is given as 0.1" and 2.5mm (not 2.54mm, which would be an exact conversion). Or perhaps it is an exact nominal 2.5mm and not ~0.0984" (less likely, I should think). There are only 3 pins on each side so the error does not add up too badly if you work things from the centers, so it's likely a moot point here, but something to watch in general.